# a site use Linux Server take long time to load

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php, httpd

i get this problem first time since 5 years i use same site same script without any change .

i have a site xxxxxxx.com (php script) use a ip http://1.1.1.1 (example) , i use centos as OS for the server . i use directadmin as panel to manage site config via address http://1.1.1.1:2222
normaly i have 16cpu site can support as 60 000 visitors online without problem , sometimes when more i get message on directadmin panel that cpu reached 100% and site down so i need to restart server and waiting , i understand it's CPU issue.

But from last week , i get a weird thing , the site start to down and up and down and became unreachabl when visiotrs became more than 5000 online , also in same time the ip http://1.1.1.1 of the site not accessible when the site down also http://1.1.1.1/phpmyadmin not working , BUT http://1.1.1.1:2222 is working normal so i can login and i need to access to service monitor to restar HTTPD and the site backs after 15s and may down also after some second if more visitors , ofcourse it is not problem of CPU.
i ask server support and they said nothing wrong and all good from theire side .

my question is : is it possible this problem can became from port network ? maybe they downgrade the speed of the port network ?

is possible that hosting provider can limit speed of port 80 ?

what i don't understand is ip of the site and apache http://1.1.1.1(port 80 normal) not works when more than 5000 online , but http://1.1.1.1:2222 panel ip stay works normal when the site down . maybe hosting provider limited or downgraded speed of port 80 ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the site is slow after you gained more than 5000 visitors online. The probable cause is that the server doesn't have enough of resources to deliver the site fast enough.

Depending on how the webpage is built, you are most likely running out of memory, CPU cycles or network bandwidth. Using chrome developer tools (ctrl-shift-I) you can get an idea exactly at what stage the browser is hanging.

If you log into the monitoring tools for your server you will probably see which resources are utilized as well.

Comment: server was reached sometimes between 60 000 and 70 000 online without any problem ( sometimes down if cpu reach 100% usage ) but with 5000 online cpu usage as i see is around 13% . normaly when ressource like CPU reach maximum i get alert on adminpanel , but in this case no alert and all resource work normal . is it possible that this problem can became if hosting company reduce or downgrade port network ?

Comment: It is possible that they have limited your bandwidth. I would check your limits from when you bought the server.

Comment: bandwith means port network speed ?

Comment: i contacted server provider and they send me test speed of server is 230 mbps download and 180 mbps upload , it that enough ?

Comment: It really depends on what the server is serving. Are you serving files that are about 20 Mbytes? Then you can only serve a few people at the same time.

Comment: its a php site , like news . no files downloads